# Cannot install linux-headers because of uname

Tags: ubuntu, apt, linux-headers

On Ubuntu (18.04.5 LTS) I tried to install linux headers (need that for acronis backup) with

```
sudo apt-get install linux -headers-`uname -r`
```

If i run that, apt lists 719 header-packages to be installed. There are also different variants like aws, oracle etc.

I think, this comes from an "uncomplete" value from uname, where i expected something like "generic", but it doesn't show that:

```
> uname -r
4.15.0
```

Some Infos:

```
> uname -a
Linux neptun 4.15.0 #1 SMP Tue Jun 9 12:58:54 MSK 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> dpkg --list | grep linux-image
ii  linux-image-4.15.0-129-generic    4.15.0-129.132    amd64    Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-extra-virtual         4.15.0.129.116    amd64    Extra drivers for Virtual Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic              4.15.0.129.116    amd64    Generic Linux kernel image

> cat /proc/version
Linux version 4.15.0 (mockbuild@builder7.eng.sw.ru) (gcc version 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) (GCC) ) #1 SMP Tue Jun 9 12:58:54 MSK 2020
```

It was a newly installed last week, and I already run update & upgrade. Nothing to install.
What can I do to resolve that?

Comment: what's the output of `cat /proc/version` if there is no `generic` word in that output string you probably not running the generic kernel. Check the boot menu (if running grub) `awk -F\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg` should show `generic` as well.

Comment: How did you install Ubuntu/where did you get your kernel from? On my fresh ubuntu 18.04 VM `uname -r` gives `4.15.0-128-generic`. Agreeing with Michael that you're possibly running a custom kernel.

Comment: added proc/version (no generic). There is no grub.cfg.
The VM was installed by the VM hoster (Strato). 
`/lib/modules` shows 4.15.0 and 4.15.0-129-generic whereas only the generic one includes the folder build and kernel

Comment: I suspect you’ll need to ask your VM host for help; only they can provide the kernel headers corresponding exactly to the kernel they installed.

Comment: Yep, already created an issue there...

Comment: Answer from host: "Acronis with our VMs is not possible". However, I think I may work, bacause Acronis just needs the headers and checks apt, if it is installed (which fails, because it checks for "4.15.0", but "4.15.0-129-generic" was installed).